# dumping a yaml file using perl

Tags: perl, yaml

I am trying to dump a yaml file in a specific format as mentioned below; how should I define my hash (%database) if I have to dump something like below?

```
-name:Fred

 Language:python

-name:Barney

 Language:perl

-name: Betty

 Language:java

-name:Wilma

 Language:ruby

open  FILE, '>>', "database.txt";

print FILE Dump(\%database);
```

Comment: Have a look at some examples: http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-1.23/lib/YAML.pod

Comment: That example is from a Perl book, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure you are showing is an array of hashes. Thus, you need to use an array, not a hash. The array contains hash references.

```
use YAML 'Dump';

my @database = (
    {
        name     => 'Fred',
        Language => 'python',
    },
    {
        name     => 'Barney',
        Language => 'perl',
    },
);

print Dump( \@database );
```

This will output

```
---
- Language: python
  name: Fred
- Language: perl
  name: Barney
```

By default, YAML will sort keys alphabetically. This is why the *Language* comes first. You can turn that off by setting `$YAML::SortKeys = 0`.

However, you cannot maintain the order of elements within the individual hashes the way you put them in your code, because [Perl's hashes are never ordered](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#Hash-overhaul)<sup>1</sup>. The order is random. So you cannot guarantee that *name* will be the first key. It might be on your machine, but it's not on mine.

There is a way to force the order, but it will only work for a very limited use-case. Y[ou can set `$YAML::SortKey` to an array reference](https://metacpan.org/source/INGY/YAML-1.23/lib/YAML/Dumper.pm#L322) of keys, and it will keep that order. This feature seems to be undocumented and is labeled as a hack in the code.

```
local $YAML::SortKeys = [qw/name Language/];
print Dump( \@database );
```

We now get

```
---
- name: Fred
  Language: python
- name: Barney
  Language: perl
```

If your data structure contains more things this might not do what you want though.

You can also use the [`Bless` function exported by YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod#Bless(perl-node,-[yaml-node-%7C-class-name])), which attaches additional meta information to the data structure. It can filter and sort specific nodes. But you'd have to create some logic to select which nodes of your data structure you want to be affected by that.

```
use YAML qw'Bless Dump';

my @database = (
    {
        name     => 'Fred',
        Language => 'python',
    },
    {
        name     => 'Barney',
        Language => 'perl',
    },
);

Bless($_)->keys( [qw/name Language/] ) for @database;
print Dump( \@database );
```

This also produces the same output

```
---
- name: Fred
  Language: python
- name: Barney
  Language: perl
```

Note that this does not change the data structure, but rather makes YAML aware of what's going on. Hence, you can't use an in-place `map` to do it, because you don't want to dump the objects created by it, but the actual data.

```
print Dump( [ map { Bless($_)->keys( [qw/name Language/] ) } @database ] );
```

This will give you a dump of the objects. That's not what you want. You would need to return `$_` after calling `Bless`.

```
print Dump( [ map { Bless($_)->keys( [qw/name Language/] ); $_ } @database ] );
```

But this is hard to read and gives no advantage. The `for` solution is way clearer.

---

<sup>1) In fact, in old Perls the order is random, but consistent on the same machine. That was a bit of a bug. Don't rely on it ever!</sup>

Comment: Isn't possible to use the `YAML::Bless` method for the members of the array? The `Bless` works only for the top-level hash-keys?

Comment: @kobame yes, that would work, too. There was an answer already about that, but the author deleted it after it got a downvote. It was just a copy of the docs though.

Comment: @kobame I've updated the answer to include that. Thank you.

Comment: GREAT Answer! :) +++

Comment: Me usually not adding comments like this, but this is an perfect example how is possible make an really great answer (which sure will help other users too) to an terribly formulated question. :)

Comment: @jm666 thanks. I actually think the question is not very bad. It's just hard to write that kind of question in a generalized way. Wrapping your head around this kind of data structure can be hard in the beginning after all. I think we should try to improve the question so it's easier to find later.